# Rails Custom Fonts Not Showing With No Errors

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I've been browsing for a while now trying to debug why my custom fonts in rails 4 aren't working. The problem i'm having is that the fonts aren't showing up on the webpage, and no text is styled with the fonts.

I have used my browsers developer tools to debug and there aren't any errors at all.

Here is the `application.css` code for my fonts:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'modeka'; src: url('/assets/modeka.otf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: 'flex'; src: url('/assets/flex.otf'); }
```

I've created a folder called `fonts` under the `assets` folder. Inside the fonts folder are both fonts.

I've tried changing the `src: url` to `src: asset-url`

I've tried adding these config lines to config/environments/production.rb

```
# Add the fonts path
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

# Precompile additional assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .otf .eot .woff .ttf )
```

I've tried adding the following code to config/application.rb

```
#config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("assets", "fonts")
```

I've added this code also to the config/application.rb file

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('/app/assets/fonts')
```

I've also tried adding `*= require_fonts` to the `application.css` file.

Nothing is working! Can anybody help

Comment: hey can you show me snap of the code ?

Comment: I have.. the first code snippet is what the font declaration code is in my `application.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

1. Save my fonts in `app/assets/fonts/` directory
2. Add `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')` to `assets.rb` file
3. Convert the css file to sass/scss file
   In this case `application.css` to `application.css.scss`
4. Then in the scss file `font-url` helper can be used:

   `@font-face { font-family: 'modeka'; src: font-url('modeka.otf'); }
   @font-face { font-family: 'flex'; src: font-url('flex.otf'); }`

Comment: I just precompiled a javascript file in the `assets.rb` config file, nothing related to the fonts or the css file and now somehow the fonts are showing... Thanks for the help anyway but i've somehow got it working

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about Rails, but if your folder structure is `/app/assets/fonts` then it surely your `src` is incorrect in your `@font-face` declaration, it should be `url('/assets/fonts/modeka.otf')`?

Comment: Rails is funny like that. The syntax i've used works fine, its a different problem. I know this because when using css images, this code works perfectly fine `background-image:url('/assets/bg.jpg');`